# jQuery: Loop print only one value

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have below code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="3" id="id_3" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="5.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="4" id="id_4" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="2.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="5" id="id_5" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="3.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>   
</table>
<script>
jQuery('table#main_table').each( function(){  
    if(jQuery(this).find("input:checkbox").is(':checked')){
         var txt = jQuery(this).find("input[name='qty[]']").val();
         alert(txt);
    }
});
```

I need to check within table if checkbox is checked then print it's qty value.  But below code only prints 1 value. Instead of all

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `each` on `<table>` which will iterate only once as there is only one table with that ID. Iterate over the `<tr>` elements in the table.

```
$('#main_table tr').each(function() {
    ...
```

```js
jQuery('table#main_table tr').each(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).find("input:checkbox").is(':checked')) {
    var txt = jQuery(this).find("input[name='qty[]']").val();
    console.log(txt);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" value="3" id="id_3" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input name="qty[]" value="5.0000" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" value="4" id="id_4" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input name="qty[]" value="2.0000" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" value="5" id="id_5" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input name="qty[]" value="3.0000" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There's better way to do this. Instead of iterating over `tr` and finding checked checkboxes, you can iterate over checked checkboxes and get the value of the associated textbox.

```
$(this)                       // Will refer to the checkbox
    .closest('td')            // Get parent <td>
    .next()                   // Get next element i.e. next <td>
    .find('[name="qty[]"]')   // Find element with name attribute value as "qty[]"
    .val()                    // Get it's value
```

```js
$('#main_table tr :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('td').next().find('[name="qty[]"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" value="3" id="id_3" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input name="qty[]" value="5.0000" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" value="4" id="id_4" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input name="qty[]" value="2.0000" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="" value="5" id="id_5" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input name="qty[]" value="3.0000" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is for tr not for table.

```js
jQuery('table#main_table tr').each( function(){  
    if(jQuery(this).find("input:checkbox").is(':checked')){
         var txt = jQuery(this).find("input[name='qty[]']").val();
         console.log(txt);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="3" id="id_3" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="5.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="4" id="id_4" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="2.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="" value="5" id="id_5" checked="checked" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input name="qty[]" value="3.0000" type="text"></td> 
    </tr>   
</table>
```